# How does BCLK work in regards to "overclocking" non K Intel CPU's

Tags: cpu, overclocking, clockspeed

I have an Intel i7 8700 with a Base Clock Rate of 3.2Ghz.

I'm researching options for OC'ing non K CPU's and came across BCLK or base clock rate a lot. I know its related to multiplying/increasing the base clock rate but what do the values of base clock rate stand for, and how does it affect the clock speed under regular, and turbo boosted speeds?

For example I can increase the BLCK to 102-103 which would make it something like this:

3.2 * 1.2 = 3.84Ghz base clock rate - However many online sources like reddit suggest it only affects the [turbo boost rate](https://www.reddit.com/r/intel/comments/7jr8tv/can_i_use_turbo_boost_for_overclocking_a_i7_8700/)

[image]

> 700 (non k) BLCK set to 102.9, Windows power option minimum processor
>   state 100%
>       Individually cores can boost to 4.7GHz,
>       All cores boosting together to 4.4GHz,
>       Minimum core speed 4.4GHz.

Answer (score 1):

The values are MHz and the CPU multiplier gives you the final clock rate. Boosting/Turbo just adds to that/modifies that.